# Doesn't metadata occupy any size?

Tags: windows, filesystems, metadata

I put **4096** characters in a text file and save it.Since every character is 1 byte, Size of the text file must be 4K byte.As you see below that's OK:

[image]

I connect my flash memory to my computer. the free space on the flash memory is **`1,717,518,336` bytes** :

[image]

I created a copy of the file in my flash memory. And again take a look at the free space. it has **`1,717,514,240` bytes** free space :

[image]

Let see what is the difference :

**1,717,518,336 - 1,717,514,240 = `4096`** bytes

---

**My question :**

**Q1:**

As you see in the last picture above, the only space that the file occupy on the flash, is the space for its contents [characters].So where is metadata file ?

I mean, when I move the file to another computer, how it understand name of file, Owner of file, Date created and modified and ... ?

Doesn't it occupy any size?!!

**Q2:**

Can I see the metadata file in the flash memory?

[image]

Appreciate your time and consideration.

Comment: Yes, meta-data *do* take place on the disk, but it's not counted when getting the size of a file. Reason being that meta-data already is allocated, and also because when doing file input you're not really interested in the the meta-data only the actual data.

Comment: I’m not sure this is a question for a  programming website. It’s better suited on another website (in addition, try creating a smaller file and look at the file size again: you might be surprised).

Comment: @JoachimPileborg how I can see the metadata file?

Comment: @KonradRudolph did you mean creating a text file with for example 1 character in it? if yes, I made it already and I saw it's size is 4K Bytes on disk. why? I suppose that the smallest size of a text file is 4k byte. I mean it have 4, 8, 12 , ... K byte size.Is that right?

Comment: @User1-St: Information on disks is stored in blocks of fixed size (4k, 8k, 16k). A file may occupy one or more blocks. Even a one-byte file occupies an entire block, which is why you sometimes see disk usage tools that show you how big the file is, and separately how much disk space it's occupying. A one-byte file would be one byte in size, but occupy 4k of disk space (if your block size is 4k).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does — but that space has already been allocated before you write the file. Adding the file just changes the contents of the file allocation table, it doesn't *extend* the file allocation table (doesn't make it bigger). For a more in-depth look at how it works, dive into articles on the FAT32 file system.

Comment: Thank you dear Crowder. but what do you mean by it has already been allocated? where? When I bought a 2GB flash memory, it has less than 2GB free space. for example 1.76 GB. Is the difference for metadata file? Can I see metadata files?

Comment: @User1-St: Yes, the difference is the metadata (and/or the difference between megabytes and [mebibytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte)), which is the overhead associated with the file system (FAT32, in your case). There are no "metadata files," the data is stored in disk blocks which are arranged according to the FAT32 scheme. To see the raw data, you'd have to have a tool that showed you raw disk blocks (or a tool specific to FAT32 that shows you the raw FAT32 data), but for the most part your file explorer program shows you the metadata.

Comment: Do you know any tools that show me raw data?

Comment: @User1-St: For Windows? Nothing immediately comes to mind, no.

Comment: @User1-St: Make sure the drive isn't mounted, and you can read the raw data of the device using all the usual tools (`cat`, `hexdump`, ...).